# How to get particles emit as trails on an object?

Tags: particles

im trying to have an object emit defined lines of trails like [this](https://youtu.be/fE8-uPkeqhc?t=5) but that consist of particles. Ive seen it done once but cannot figure it out myself and have lost my reference. Can someone help?

Answer (score 6):

You could make an object follow a curve with a *Follow Path* constraint, then give it a particle system with *Emission > Number >* as many as the amount of frames you need for your animation, *Source > Emit From > Vertices*, *Velocity > Normals > 0*, *Field Weights > Gravity > 0*, *Vertex Groups > Density > Group* (with a single vertex as vertex group so that the particles are aligned). Here is what it gives:

[image]